# Iterate over each row in matrix Octave

Tags: octave

How do I iterate over each row in *Z* where *Z* is a *2 * m* matrix:

```
6.1101,17.592
5.5277,9.1302
8.5186,13.662
```

How do I access each *Z(i)(j)* inside this loop?

For example:

```
for i = z
  fprintf('Iterating over row: '+ i);
  disp (i:1);
  disp (i:2);
end
```

Would output:

```
Iterating over row: 1
6.1101
17.592
Iterating over row: 2
5.5277
9.1302
Iterating over row: 3
8.5186
13.662
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you use `for i = z` when z is a matrix, then i takes the value of the first column of z (6.1101; 5.5277; 8.5186), then the second column and so on. See [octave manual: The-for-Statement](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/The-for-Statement.html#The-for-Statement)

If you want to iterate over all elements you could use

```
z = [6.1101,17.592;5.5277,9.1302;8.5186,13.662]

for i = 1:rows(z)
  for j = 1:columns(z)
    printf("z(%d,%d) = %f\n", i, j, z(i,j));
  endfor
endfor
```

which outputs:

```
z(1,1) = 6.110100
z(1,2) = 17.592000
z(2,1) = 5.527700
z(2,2) = 9.130200
z(3,1) = 8.518600
z(3,2) = 13.662000
```

But keep in mind that for loops are slow in octave so it may be desirable to use a vectorized method. Many functions can use a matrix input for most common calculations.

For example if you want to calculate the overall sum:

```
octave> sum (z(:))
ans =  60.541
```

Or the difference between to adjacent rows:

```
octave> diff (z)
ans =

  -0.58240  -8.46180
   2.99090   4.53180
```

Comment: Coming from a strong JavaScript background the idea of vectorized methods seems foreign to me. If my goal was to compute the sum of all iterations *m* of *X* where each iteration arithmetic is performed on *X(i,j)* what would an example of that look like if there were no for loops?

Comment: If you want to calculate the sum from all elements in z you could use "sum (z(:))". You could also use "sum"(it's an octave function) to calculate the row or column sum. See "help sum" and the DIM argument. Octave was designed to work on matrices so it is really, really unlikely that you need to loop over a vector or matrix.

Comment: This answer is so close that I got really confused when it didn't work. As indicated in the manual you link, for doesn't iterate over the rows of a matrix but the columns. You would need to transpose to get the intended effect.

Comment: @Tim: You are right, I inverted colum and row in the first sentence

Comment: BE VERY CAREFUL about using "i" as the name of variable in Octave or Matlab.  "for i = 1:rows(z)" This will change the global variable i from having the value sqrt(-1) to in this case the number of rows in the object named z.  So if you do any complex number manipulation after this code, such as  a = (2, 3i); will get strange behaviour!

Answer (score 2):

You can transpose the matrix first and then do a `for` statement like so:

```
for i = z'
    disp(i(1))
    disp(i(2))
end
```

Although in this case you won't have an index stating which row you are using